# stop Firestore warning that everyone can read data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting a warning email from Firebase Firestore every day saying that:

> "any user can read your entire database"

But in my case it's an open database where everyone can read the data.
I have set up my security rules like so:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'xxxxx';
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem and **how do I stop this warning email?**

Comment: It turns out this is possible. I didn't know this until now, so I'm now going to turn off the alerts on some of my own public databases. :)

Comment: Hehe i’m happy !! Thanks a lot. Appreciate your upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can turn these emails off from the Alerts settings in the Firebase console

> To configure alerts, do the following:
>
> 1. Click  bell icon in the upper-right corner of the Firebase console, to see the list of recent Alerts.
> 2. Choose the project that you want to receive email alerts about.
> 3. Check relevant boxes to choose whether you'd like alerts in the Firebase Console, over email, or both.

Also see: [Configure Email Alerts](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7276542?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been ignoring these alerts for over a year now despite having an intentionally open database with no sensitive info in it.. Btw this button is no longer labelled "Firebase alerts", its just a notification bell in the upper right corner for anyone whos trying to figure this out.