# Firebase Realtime Database: Google warning for write rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I received a warning from Google (via e-mail) that the following realtime database rules are unsafe. It says that every authenticated user can write into the whole database, but I think that this is not true. Am I wrong?

The 'schema' has two database objects: 'items' and 'users'.
The rules are as following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('admin').val() == true"
    },
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks and regards
Simon

Comment: I won't say `".read": true` rule for `users` node is secure as you are exposing all users' data to everyone (that might potentially include confidential data). If that's your use case and all information is public, then you can ignore the warnings imo.

Comment: I don't think these rules should trigger the alert, but if they continue to do so you can disable the alert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388991/stop-firestore-warning-that-everyone-can-read-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much for your answer. The alert was triggered again couple of hours ago. Seems to be a false alert in that case. Thanks and regards Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to be correct and the write rules inhibit some users to write into the database, so that the warning appears to be a false warning.